# i want to pass data from axios to an object in the state

Tags: python, django, reactjs, axios

i tried this but it didn't work, i dont know how to get the array **labels** which is in the object **chartData** to pass the data to it

```
state = {
        chartData: {
            labels:[],
            datasets:[{
                    label:'items',
                    data:[]
            }]
        }

      }

      componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/chart/').then(result => {
          this.setState({
            labels:result.data.label,
            data:result.data.quantity
          });
          console.log(this.state.chartData)
        });

      }
```

and **console.log()** gave me an empty arrays and here is the result

```
Object
labels: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
datasets: Array(1)
0: {label: "items", data: Array(0), _meta: {…}}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

and here is my backend function:

```
class chart(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class=chartserializer
    def get(self,*args,**kwrgs):
        names=[]
        quant=[]

        od=order_details.objects.order_by('product__name','quantity').distinct('product__name')

        for i in od :
           name=products.objects.get(name=i.product.name) 
           qty=list(order_details.objects.filter(product=i.product).aggregate(Sum('quantity')).values())[0]
           names.append(name.name)
           quant.append(qty)
        data={
            "label":names,
            "quantity":quant
        }    
        return Response(data)
```

and it's result:

```
{
    "label": [
        "dress",
        "jacket"
    ],
    "quantity": [
        10,
        17
    ]
}
```

Comment: `console.log()` might happen before when `setState` is finished. if `result.data.label` gives you the correct data then the state will be set just fine.

Comment: i dont think so cuz chart also doesn't show any data and i did console.log to see whether if data is coming through or not and it gave me nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, I think you are not organizing you data correctly when returning a json. They should be grouped by `order_detail` so you can get meaning from each of them i.e. I would do return something like this from backend.

```
[
    {
        "label": "dress",
        "quantity": 10
    },
    {
        "label": "jacket",
        "quantity": 17
    },
]
```

There your json is self explaining. You have an array of order_details, each object inside the array is an order_detail which has a `label` and a `quantity`.

Then in the frontend you would just iterate on each of them. Otherwise you will have to keep indexes to refer to each of them since you are receiving two arrays of not directly related values.

Answer (score 0):

*this* being used in arrow brackets will point to the function *result*

so your function should be

```
componentDidMount() {
    self = this;
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/chart/').then(result => {
      self.setState({
        labels:result.data.label,
        data:result.data.quantity
      });
      console.log(this.state.chartData)
    });

  }
```

Comment: it gives me a syntax error when trying to write **chartData.labels**

Comment: still the same 


```
./src/components/charts.js
  Line 23:22:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  21 |         axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/chart/').then(result => {
  22 |           self.setState({
> 23 |             chartData.labels:result.data.label,
     |                      ^
  24 |             data:result.data.quantity
  25 |           });
  26 |           console.log(this.state.chartData)
```